# Flask: Trouble passing app_context correctly

Tags: python, flask

I am challenged, I believe, passing the argument app in the call to the Thread function.  I currently am using a value of current_app.app_context().  When this is passed to the send_async_email function it errors out indicating that there is no attribute app_context.  I understand the message but can't seem to come up with the right syntax.

I believe I need to change the argument in the call to Thread or I need to change the with app.app_context(): line in the send_async_email function header.

Appreciate the guidance on how to correctly setup the argument and pass it.

```
from threading import Thread
from flask import current_app, render_template
from flask_mail import Message
from . import mail

def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)
def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    msg = Message(current_app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + ' ' + subject,
                  sender=current_app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
    msg.body = render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs)
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[current_app.app_context(), msg])
    thr.start()
    return thr
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is here `Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[current_app.app_context(), msg])`. Change the `current_app.app_context()` to `current_app`

Comment: I modified  the Thread call to pass `args=[current_app, msg]`.  When I inspect `current_app` prior to the Thread call it is pointing to a `{Flask} <Flask 'app'>` object.

Stepping into `send_async_email(app, msg)`, and inspecting `app` it is a `{LocalProxy} <LocalProxy unbound>` object.   Inspecting `app.app_context()` shows this error: 

{RuntimeError}Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context().